# Pular caminho que o CSS "percorre"

Tags: html, css

Posso "pular o caminho que o css percorre"?

Exemplo:

```
<body>
<div class="a">
     <ul class="b">
         <li class="c">
          Teste
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Ai por exemplo, quero pegar o li, mas como é "muita coisa", em vez de fazer isso:

```
.a .b .c{
  blablabla;
}
```

Posso fazer isso?

```
.a .c {
  blablabla;
}
```

Comment: Sim pode, o espaçamento não é um caminho, é uma regra e funciona como "cascata"

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo sua pergunta pode sim.

Mas complementando, o código abaixo

```
.a .c {
  blablabla;
}
```

irá pegar qualquer elemento com a classe `c` dentro de `a` independente da hierarquia, ou seja

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="c"> </div>
</div>
```

e

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div clas="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

terão a mesma regra.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da forma perguntata, a única diferença é o estilo será aplicado nos elementos dentro de `a` que possuem a classe `c`. Ou seja, se você possuir algum elemento fora de `b` com a classe `c`, ele também receberá os estilos.

Note também que você pode colocar "estilizar" somente a classe `c`, esquecendo as classes `a` e `b`.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.a {
  background-color: green;
}

.a .c {
  background-color: blue;
}

.d {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <ul class="b">
    <li class="c">
      Teste
    </li>
    <li class="d">
      Teste
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="c"> fora de b</p>
</div>
```